Using Delegated Permissions with System-Assigned Managed Identity in Logic Apps for shared mail box email Attachments
I am new to Azure Logic Apps. My goal is to create a Logic App that retrieves an Excel file attachment from a shared mailbox and places it into (ADLS). For authentication, I'm utilizing a system assigned managed identity within Logic Apps.
Due to restrictions, I cannot use a password for the shared mailbox to automate this process. My research suggests that utilizing an HTTP trigger to make a Graph API call could authenticate and connect to the shared mailbox. This method would typically require using the application permission 'Mail.Read' on a service principal in Azure. However, my backend team is not willing to grant application permissions but is ready to provide delegated permissions on the service principal. Delegated permissions do not seem to work with a system assigned managed identity.
I am looking for guidance on the steps I need to take to achieve this with the given constraints. I am wondering if there's a way to make delegated permissions work for a system assigned managed identity or if there's an alternative approach to accomplishing this task.
Any advice or insights would be greatly appreciated. Please refer to any step by step guide for creating a logic app for this scenario.
Attempted to run using individual credentials.

You should see if your backend team will accept the approach of using an ApplicationAccessPolicy to constrain what mailboxes your application identity has access to, using the process in the following link. I am using this for several mailboxes in Azure Functions but there is no reason why it should not work for a Logic App, it is at least worth the attempt.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access
